# Wrong number of arguments error

Tags: error

The following key is supposed to go to the end of the *visual* line and switch to insert mode:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "A") (lambda () (interactive) (end-of-visual-line) (evil-insert)))
```

However, the function returns the error: wrong number of arguments: (1 . 3), 0.
What is the correct version?

Comment: `evil-insert` requires at least one argument (see its docstring). Alternatively, you could use `(evil-insert-state)`.

Comment: The question is likely a duplicate. Search for your error message. Delete the question when you find that it's a duplicate. Thx.